# C# logging library that integrates with Azure Diagnostics

Tags: library, c#, logs

I'm looking for a C# logging library that will work well with Azure.  Azure Diagnostics listens for `System.Diagnostics.Trace` messages, so the library needs to support `Trace` as a log sink.